# Perl wildcards in the file paths

Tags: perl

I am working on my project where the GNU Makefile should automatically test my Perl program with different input files. I have this code which reads only one file from `inputs` directory, searches stop words and outputs `out.txt` file with frequency table of non-stop words.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Lingua::StopWords qw(getStopWords);

my %found;

my $src = '/programu-testavimas/1-dk/trunk/tests/inputs/test.txt';
my $des = '/programu-testavimas/1-dk/trunk/tests/outputs/out.txt';

open(SRC,'<',$src) or die $!;
open(DES,'>',$des) or die $!;
my $stopwords = getStopWords('en');
while( my $line = <SRC>){
    ++$found{$_} for grep { !$stopwords->{$_} }
            split /\s+/, lc $line;
}
print DES $_, "\t\t", $found{$_}, $/ for sort keys %found;

close(SRC);
close(DES);
```

My goal is to test many files with separate `case.sh` scripts where the input files should be different in each case, this is one of the case:

```
#!/bin/sh
perl /programu-testavimas/1-dk/trunk/scripts/test.pl /programu-testavimas/1-dk/trunk/tests/inputs/test.txt > /home/aleksandra/programų-testavimas/1-dk/trunk/tests/outputs/out.txt
```

Then, my Makefile at once should test program with different inputs in each case. So, right now I'm struggling with my Perl code where my input file is only one individual and I need to make it read different files in `inputs` directory. How can I change path correctly that bash scripts could have each case with individual input file?

EDIT: I tried this with glob function but it outputs empty file

```
open(DES,'>',$des) or die $!;
my $stopwords = getStopWords('en');
for my $file ( glob $src ) {
  open(SRC,'<',$file) or die "$! opening $file";
  while( my $line = <SRC>){
      ++$found{$_} for grep { !$stopwords->{$_} }
              split /\s+/, lc $line;
  }
  print DES $_, "\t\t", $found{$_}, $/ for sort keys %found;
  close(SRC);
}

close(DES);
```

Comment: If you need to iterate on a glob: `say for glob <*>`

Comment: What is the "bash" tag doing in this question? `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh, not bash (some operating systems make it a symlink, but when bash is started under the `sh` name it runs in POSIX compatibility mode); there's no bash here anywhere.

Comment: If `$src = '/programu-testavimas/1-dk/trunk/tests/inputs/test.txt'`, then `glob $src` isn't expected to evaluate to anything except that original value -- it'd be different if you had, say, `$src = '/programu-testavimas/1-dk/trunk/tests/inputs/*.txt'`. Anyhow -- it would be helpful to focus on building a [mre] here; if you don't need `getStopWords` to demonstrate the problem getting a list of files, f/e, taking that out makes it easier for others to run your code without changes. (Even more so if that code were to stop depending on a `programu-testavimas` directory nobody but you will have).

Comment: Cross-posted to perlmonks:  https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11148554

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but to me it sounds like you have different shell scripts, each calling your perl script with a different input, and redirecting your perl's script output to a new file.

You don't need to glob anything in your perl script. It already has all the information it needs: which file to read. Your shell script/Makefile is handling the rest.

So given the shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
perl /path/to/test.pl /path/to/input.txt > /path/to/output.txt
```

Then in your perl script, simply read from the file provided via the first positional parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Lingua::StopWords qw(getStopWords);

my %found;

my $stopwords = getStopWords('en');
while(my $line = <>) {
    ++$found{$_} for grep { !$stopwords->{$_} }
            split /\s+/, lc $line;
}
print $_, "\t\t", $found{$_}, $/ for sort keys %found;
```

`while(<>)` will read from STDIN or from ARGV.

Your shell script could then call your perl script with different inputs and define outputs:

```
#!/bin/sh
for input in /path/to/*.txt; do
  perl /path/to/test.pl "$input" > "$input.out"
done
```